# scikit-learn LabelPropagation replaces original labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I try to learn scikit-learn and applied the LabelPropagation example for missing labels:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/semi_supervised/plot_label_propagation_structure.html#example-semi-supervised-plot-label-propagation-structure-py

Adding one "wrong" label to the outer circle by

```
...
labels     = -np.ones(n_samples)
labels[0]  = outer
labels[1]  = inner
labels[2]  = outer
labels[-1] = inner
...
```

I get the original label replaced by the other class, even if alpha is set to 1.0. As far as I understood, if alpha is 1.0 none of the original labels will be replaced.

Does anyone understand what happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the LabelPropagation method or the LabelSpreading ? Can you show how you are calling the method?
According to the [user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html#label-propagation) it shouldn't matter, with alpha set to 1 all already labeled samples should keep the original labels.

Comment: If you look at the example it is label spreading. I took exactly the above linked example, so you can check what happens.

Answer (score 0):

LabelSpreading and LabelPropagation will finally be fixed in version 0.19